# Integral of a continuous function continuous on a compact set w.r.t. the pointwise convergence topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, compactness

Take $K:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to [l,h] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. For every $\tau\in [0,1]$, $K(\cdot,\tau)$ is continuous. Let $X$ be some compact subset of $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$. Does it follow that the map
$$
x \mapsto \int_0^1 K(x(\tau),\tau) d\tau
$$
is continuous w.r.t. the pointwise convergence topology on $X$ (assuming the integral exists for every $x\in X$)?

Comment: Please avoid multiple questions in one post.

Comment: Okay, removed the 'if not' part.

Comment: More precisely, it should written as ``Does it follow that the map 
$$
x\mapsto\int_{0}^{1}K(x(\tau),\tau)d\tau
$$
is continuous ...

Comment: Dominated convergence ensures that if one has a *sequence* of elements $(x_n)$ in $X$ converging to $x$, then the corresponding integrals converge. So the only thing that could go wrong must be when $X$ is not first countable.

Comment: If $X$ is not assumed to be compact, then this is certainly false. Say, if you just let $X$ contain indicator functions of finite subsets of $[0, 1]$ and the indicator function of $[0, 1]$ itself, and let $K(x, \tau) = x$. But the closure of $X$ would then contain all indicator functions, so lots of non-measurable functions and you wouldn’t have integrability for all $x \in X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further reflections, I realized ideas similar to those in my second comment lead to a counterexample assuming the continuum hypothesis. Martin's Axiom is sufficient for this purpose as well, but for simplicity I'll just work with CH. Again, I'll set $K(x, \tau) = x$. Under CH, we identify $[0, 1]$ with $\omega_1$. Let $X$ consist of all indicator functions of intervals in $\omega_1$ of the form $[0, \omega)$ for $\omega \leq \omega_1$ (or, to put it another way: $X$ consists of indicator functions of all initial segments of $\omega_1$). One can then see that $X$ is closed in $[0, 1]^{[0, 1]}$, so it is compact. Now, if $x \in X$ is the indicator function of $[0, \omega)$ for $\omega < \omega_1$, then it is supported on a countable set, so $\int_0^1 K(x(\tau), \tau) d\tau = \int_0^1 x(\tau) d\tau = 0$. The only other element of $X$ is the indicator function of the entire $[0, 1]$, so its integral is 1. But the indicator function of $[0, \omega)$ converges to the indicator function of the entire set as $\omega \rightarrow \omega_1$, showing that your map is not continuous.

Comment: Thank you! I am also interested in a more specific question which might preclude such counterexamples. I will post it in a separate question soon.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4807035/maximum-of-integral-over-a-compact-space-is-the-argument-correct Here is the follow up