# Maximum of integral over a compact space: is the argument correct?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

**I am interested in the following problem:**

Consider the functional $F:[0,1]^{[0,1]}\to \mathbb{R}$ (so from functions that map $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ to the reals):
$$
F[x]=\int_0^1 J(x(\theta),\theta) d\theta. 
$$
$J(\cdot,\theta)$ maps to a bounded interval and is continuous for every $\theta\in [0,1]$, and such that $J(x(\theta),\theta)$ is measurable for every **weakly increasing** $x\in [0,1]^{[0,1]}$.

Let $X$ be the set of **weakly increasing** $x\in [0,1]^{[0,1]}$. Show that the solution maximum of $F[x]$ over $X$  exists.

**My attempt is below. Does the argument work?**

Endow $X$ with the point-wise convergence topology. Since it is a product topology, Tychonoff's theorem tells us that the set of $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ is compact. I can further show that the set $X$ is a closed subset of $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$, and so is also compact.

Now, by the Weierstrass theorem, it suffices to show that $F$ is continuous in $x$. For that it in turn suffices to show that for any sequence in $X$, $x_n \to x$, we have $F[x_n]\to F[x]$. Fix such an $x_n$. Since we are in the topology of point-wise convergence, we have that $x_n(\theta) \to x(\theta)$ for every $\theta\in [0,1]$. By the continuity of $J(\cdot,\theta)$ this gives $J(x_n(\theta),\theta)\to J(x(\theta),\theta)$ for every $\theta \in [0,1]$. Hence, the sequence of functions $h_n(\theta) := J(x_n(\theta),\theta)$ converges p.w. to $J(x(\theta),\theta)$. Hence, by the Dominated Convergence Theorem we get that $\int_0^1 J(x_n(\theta),\theta)d\theta \to \int_0^1 J(x(\theta),\theta) d\theta$. This shows that $F$ is continuous on $X$ and hence lets us apply the Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: The argument does not work as is. The issue is the topology on $X$ may not be fully captured by convergence of sequences (unless $X$ is first countable). So if you only consider a sequence $x_n$ converging to $x$ and prove that $F[x_n] \rightarrow F[x]$, this is not enough to establish the continuity of $F$. (Think about it: your argument does not depend on any specific properties of the $X$ you’re using apart from it being closed in $[0, 1]^{[0, 1]}$. If the argument works as is, it would have applied to my counterexample to your previous question as well, but that is not the case.)

Comment: This argument could potentially be saved by noting that the map actually quotients through the restriction map $[0, 1]^{[0, 1]} \rightarrow [0, 1]^{\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]}$ since a non-decreasing function can only have countably many points of discontinuity, so the values at points of discontinuity do not matter for the integral. $[0, 1]^{\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]}$ is also first countable (in fact, second countable), so it’s enough to consider limits of sequences. The only problem is that I’m not sure whether pointwise convergence on rationals implies a.e. convergence.

Comment: Also, this was in your previous question, so I was implicitly assuming it. But I just realized you didn’t write it down this time: in order to apply dominated convergence, you need something like $J$ has bounded range. Without that assumption this is probably false.

Comment: I was wondering if this works for completing the proof using the restriction map: Any $x \in X$ is a.e. equal to its left-continuous version, so we can take all functions to be LC. Take a sequence of LC $x_n$ that converge to $x$ (also left cont) on $\mathbb{Q}$. Fix any $\theta\in [0,1]$; then there is a sequence of $\tau_m \in \mathbb{Q}$ that converges to $\tau$ from the left. Since all $x_n$ are LC, for any $n$, $x_n(\tau_m)\to x_n(\theta)$ as $m\to \infty$. Since we also know that for any $m$, $x_n(\theta_m) \to x(\theta_m)$ as $n\to\infty$, shouldn't that imply $x_n\to x$ p.w.?

Comment: Not really. You can’t change the order of the two limits. (You want something like $\lim_m x(\theta_m) = \lim_m \lim_n x_n(\theta_m) = \lim_n \lim_m x_n(\theta_m) = \lim_n x_n(\theta)$, but the limits w.r.t. $m$ and w.r.t. $n$ can’t really be exchanged unless there’s some uniform convergence, which isn’t the case here.) Also, pointwise limits of LC functions don’t have to be LC. (Think, say, spike functions at 1 of shrinking widths.) So the pointwise limit of $x_n$ doesn’t have to be the LC version of $x$ - the most one could hopeful is a.e. convergence.

Comment: $X$ is the Helly space. You can read about its properties [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly_space) or [here](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000105/properties) and see also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_selection_theorem). It is first countable and sequentially compact. So it's sequential and your argument shows $F$ is continuous. (Alternatively you can argue that since it's sequentially compact and $F$ is sequentially continuous, $F$ must have and attain an upper bound).

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Oh, I didn’t realize it is first countable. In that case my more convoluted argument isn’t really necessary. (Is this because for any fixed $f \in X$, it is enough consider basic neighborhoods defined by rational radii at rational points and points of discontinuity of $f$?)

Comment: @DavidGao, yep, I think that's right. The point being that if $f$ is continuous at $x$, then $g(x)$ is close to $f(x)$ if $g(x^-)$ is close to $f(x^-)$ and $g(x^+)$ is close to $f(x^+)$ for some suitably chosen rationals $x^\pm$ on either side of $x$. This argument appears in "Counterexamples in Topology" as example 107. I like your answer though, and I very much agree that the argument about continuity of $F$ needed more care/justification!

Comment: Thank you both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a way to prove this. It's a bit tricky, mainly because a.e. convergence does not define a topology, so I need to figure out a specific co-null set on which the convergence happens actually everywhere. The following is the full argument:

We first observe, for any non-decreasing function $f$, its points of discontinuity are countable. So off of a countable set (and therefore a.e.) $f(\theta) = \lim_{q \rightarrow \theta} f(q)$ with $q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]$. As the integral $F[x]$ does not change if $x$ is only altered on a null set, we see that $F$ quotients through the restriction map $q: [0, 1]^{[0, 1]} \rightarrow [0, 1]^{\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]}$, i.e., $F = F' \circ q$ for some $F': q(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. It then suffices to prove $F'$ is continuous. We observe that $[0, 1]^{\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]}$, and therefore $q(X)$, is second countable, so it suffices to prove $F'$ is sequentially continuous.

Interpreting what this actually means, we see that we need to prove the following: suppose $X \ni x_n \rightarrow x \in X$ pointwise on $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]$, then $F[x_n] \rightarrow F[x]$. We observe that it suffices to prove that $x_n \rightarrow x$ pointwise a.e., since then the continuity of $J(\cdot, \theta)$ for each $\theta \in [0, 1]$ implies $J(x_n(\theta), \theta) \rightarrow J(x(\theta), \theta)$ for a.e.-$\theta$, whence Lebesgue dominated convergence implies $F[x_n] \rightarrow F[x]$.

Now, we observe that for any nondecreasing function $f$, all its points of discontinuity are jump discontinuities, i.e., $f$ is discontinuous at $\theta$ iff $\lim_{q \rightarrow \theta^-} f(q) \neq \lim_{q \rightarrow \theta^+} f(q)$. Again, we may consider in the above limit only $q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]$, so in particular if two nondecreasing functions restrict to the same function on $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]$, then they must share the same set of points of discontinuity. Now, let $X$ be the set of points of discontinuity of $x$ and let $Y = [0, 1] \setminus X$. We claim that $x_n \rightarrow x$ pointwise on $Y$. Since $Y$ is co-countable and therefore co-null, this will prove the result.

Since convergence pointwise on $Y$ defines a topology, it suffices to prove that for any subnet $(x_{n_\lambda})_\lambda$ of $(x_n)$, there exists a further subnet which converges to $x$ pointwise on $Y$. To do so, we simply observe that $X$ is compact, so there is a further subnet $(x_{n_{\lambda_\eta}})_\eta$ which converges pointwise to some $x' \in X$. It suffices to prove $x'(\theta) = x(\theta)$ for all $\theta \in Y$. Since $x_n \rightarrow x$ pointwise on $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]$, we necessarily have $x'$ and $x$ coincide on $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]$. As we have observed in the last paragraph, they then must share the same set of points of discontinuity, namely $X$. So for any $\theta \in Y = [0, 1] \setminus X$, we have $x'(\theta) = \lim_{q \rightarrow \theta} x'(q) = \lim_{q \rightarrow \theta} x(q) = x(\theta)$, where we used the fact that $x$ and $x'$ coincide on $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0, 1]$. This proves the claim.

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful!